# Store data from Pig relation into Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, apache-pig, datastax-enterprise

I have the following Cassandra table:

```
CREATE TABLE segments (
  b text,
  s int,
  c int,
  PRIMARY KEY (b)
)
```

and the following Pig relation:

```
data: {b: chararray,s: long,c: long}
```

which I am loading from a file stored in PigStorage

```
data = LOAD 'some_file' as (b:chararray,s:long,c:long);
```

I am trying to store the Pig relation into the Cassandra table unsuccessfully. I tried:

```
to_cassandra = FOREACH (GROUP data ALL) 
  GENERATE 
    TOTUPLE(TOTUPLE('b',data.b)),
    TOTUPLE('s',data.s),
    TOTUPLE('c',data.c);
STORE to_cassandra INTO 
  'cql://pv/segments?
    output_query=UPDATE%20pv.segments%20SET%20s%3D%3F%2Cc%3D%3F'
  USING CqlStorage();
```

where the decoded output query is:

```
UPDATE pv.segments SET s=?,c=?
```

but I get the following:

```
[main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - 
  ERROR: java.lang.ClassCastException: 
    org.apache.pig.data.DefaultDataBag cannot be cast to org.apache.pig.data.DataByteArray
```

which is kind of cryptic. Which one is the offending field? How do I fix this?

**EDIT**

I ran `illustrate to_cassandra;` and got:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| data     | b:chararray                                                  | s:long     | c:long     | 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          | 03Wat7NfMi8QiE4IlHeTmbOEfLNkvlzfG5znff62KvSzpm09eTBWCxcdotuB | 1          | 1          | 
|          | 0qadR3YpgVEwYsORBHFMfAh4OFk7IrROyCq7RDibchBpAKfSWAjOHDAyfzPG | 1          | 1          | 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1-3     | group:chararray     | data:bag{:tuple(b:chararray,s:long,c:long)}                                                                                                  | 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|         | all                 | {(03Wat7NfMi8QiE4IlHeTmbOEfLNkvlzfG5znff62KvSzpm09eTBWCxcdotuB, 1, 1), (0qadR3YpgVEwYsORBHFMfAh4OFk7IrROyCq7RDibchBpAKfSWAjOHDAyfzPG, 1, 1)} | 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| to_cassandra     | org.apache.pig.builtin.totuple_org.apache.pig.builtin.totuple_29_30:tuple(org.apache.pig.builtin.totuple_29:tuple(:chararray,:bag{:tuple(b:chararray)}))                         | org.apache.pig.builtin.totuple_31:tuple(:chararray,:bag{:tuple(s:long)})                     | org.apache.pig.builtin.totuple_32:tuple(:chararray,:bag{:tuple(c:long)})                     | 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  | ((b, {(03Wat7NfMi8QiE4IlHeTmbOEfLNkvlzfG5znff62KvSzpm09eTBWCxcdotuB), (0qadR3YpgVEwYsORBHFMfAh4OFk7IrROyCq7RDibchBpAKfSWAjOHDAyfzPG)}))                                          | (s, {(1), (1)})                                                                              | (c, {(1), (1)})                                                                              | 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue with your grouping, since it's producing arrays for each field instead of individual values, which is what Cassandra expects.  Your output should ultimately look like:

```
((b, 03Wat7NfMi8QiE4IlHeTmbOEfLNkvlzfG5znff62KvSzpm09eTBWCxcdotuB)), (s, 1), (c, 1)
```

... in order to match your schema.  Since your output schema directly matches your input, the purpose of the grouping is unclear.

Comment: Is `DataByteArray` an array of bags? Also, I load data from a file that contains N rows, each with those three fields, am I setting the schema wrong?

Comment: i.e., I load the data with `data = load 'some_file' as (b:chararray,s:long,c:long);`

Comment: What does pig output when you run `illustrate to_cassandra`?  Does pig complain after that line or when you try to execute `store`?

Comment: I haven't tried `illustrate` but I did try `describe` and it worked. It fails when I run it. I'll try running `illustrate`.

Comment: Great...  What is the output?  I want to see that it matches what Cassandra is expecting, since it seems that the issue is a mismatch while doing the store.

Comment: yeah the last line doesn't look right. I am not sure what's going on there.